# Binding Crittercism for Mono for Android

Tags: android, binding, xamarin.android, crittercism

I'm trying to use Crittercism for Mono for Android. I've managed to compile the binding project of the crittercism jar with the following Metadata.xml

```
<metadata>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='crittercism.android']/class[@name='a.a']" />  
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='crittercism.android']/class[@name='a.c']" />  
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='crittercism.android']/class[@name='b.b']" />  
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='crittercism.android']/class[@name='d.a']" />  
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='crittercism.android']/class[@name='f.a']" />  
</metadata>
```

If I inspect the resulting dll with the assembly browser in mono develop, the init method

```
Com.Crittercism.App.Crittercism.Init(Context c, String token);
```

Is missing from it. The removal of classes I mentioned above seem to me to only be internal obfuscated classes, but I'm not sure about that. Has anyone managed to use this successfully?

Edit:

In the build log I can find a line

```
Unknown parameter type org.json.JSONObject... found in method Init in type Com.Crittercism.App.Crittercism
```

Maybe it is related to that? I have tried adding a json.org jar as reference jar in the binding project, but no success so far.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any progress?

Comment: Have you done it? Could you publish bindings project or post an instruction?

Answer (score 0):

Co-founder of [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) here.  If you're still having trouble with the binding, we actually just released an officially supported Xamarin Plugin which should fix that error. You can download it here:

http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism